# Vue router redirecting to home page on reload

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have an vue app with many routes. Whenever I try to reload a page it is always redirecting me to the home page instead of refreshing the current page.

Below is my router setting:

```
export default new Router({
mode: 'history',
base: process.env.BASE_URL,
routes: [
 {
   path: '/',
   name: 'home',
   component: Home,
   children: [
   {
      path: "/dashboard",
      name: 'dashboard',
      component: DashboardView
   },
   {
      path: "/About",
      name:'about',
      component: About
   },
   { 
      path: "/comments",
      name:'comments',
      component: Comments
   },
  ]
}
```

How to refresh the current page instead of redirection to home page.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming your `process.env.BASE_URL` exists and it is correct, the `home` component is your entry point.
From your routes list you placed `About` as a child of `home`, probably you meant that to be outside.

Anyway, try to make all of them non-children, once you are sure they all work as expected, try the nested children approach again but please note from the Docs:

```
Note that nested paths that start with / will be treated as a root path. This allows you to leverage the component nesting without having to use a nested URL.
```

Reference:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html